# Randomly generating obstacles in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Currently I'm creating game in which whole level is generated when player moves. I have working script for that, but now I want to generate obstacles in front of the player. My idea is to add empty object to my terrain segment(these are dynamically generated) and then instantiate random obstacles at their position at runtime. The only thing i don't know is how this script should pick random empty object(empty object is child of the segment) to instantiate this obstacle? The script which generates level is attached to player.

Comment: Don not expect people to write code for you. At-least provide a code. Provide what you have tried and someone can help you.

Comment: My problem is that i can't find any function that would return child or it transform.position and i'm stuck. I have seen some functions that should do this but none of them worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives you an idea of how to do it.
Spawns a random game object to one of the empty gameobjects around your terrain.

```
//Add the random objects in the inspector
public List<GameObject> gameObjects;
//Spawn points around the terrain
public List<Transform> emptyTransforms;

foreach(var item in emptyTransforms){
    var objToSpawn = gameObjects[Random.Range(0, gameObjects.Length)];
    var objSpawned = Instantiate(objToSpawn, emptyTransforms[Random.Range(0, emptyTransforms.Length)].position, Quaternion.identity);
    objSpawned.transform.SetParent(newParent);
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to get this child gameobjects in script? That would help a lot.

Comment: @faken You don't need to put random objects as child of empty game objects or vice versa. 

Just put the empty game objects around your scene, and then drag the random game objects prefabs(the ones in your folder, that you are instantiating) and the scene empty gameobjects to the public lists in the script.

Comment: Ok it works very well but I have one more problem: how can I destroy these objects after terrain segment they were generated by is destroyed?

Comment: @faken See updated answer.

Comment: This doesn't work for me because there are always three segments and when the last one is destroyed it destroys aleso the new randomly place objects. Is there any way to solve that?

Comment: Maybe should I instantiate them as child of this segment?

Comment: @faken That might make more sense yes, you wouldn't need destroy code then.

You need http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.SetParent.html

I'v edited my code again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106858/discussion-between-martin-mazza-dawson-and-faken) if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Random.Range function to calculate random values. Then make the values within bounds of where you want obstacles to spawn and create a Vector3 with those values. Now the obstacles are spawned in a random area.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a fixed list of possible positions, just store them in a public variable in the script. If your empty gameobjects are the positions, create a `public GameObject[] positions;`, populate it and use something like `Random.Range` to pick one of it.

Also I suggest you have a look at item pooling and don't instantiate new objects all the time (and probably destroy "old" ones). That is better for your performance.